# How to insert a PHP script into attribute "selected" (HTML 5)

Tags: php, html, insert, attributes, selected

I'm trying to insert a PHP script into a selected attribute in HTML5 ,but I have failed with syntax.

> Error :"The value of selected attribute is made invalid because it's not supported by the current schema".

It looks like this... How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
<div>
    <label>Select author here:</label>
    <select name="author">
        <option value="">Select an author</option>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
          <option value="<?php htmlout($author['id']);?>" 
            selected="<?php ?>">    

            <?php htmlout($author['name']);?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `htmlout()` ?

Comment: htmlout is 'echo', help me

Comment: If it's a `book` entry form, you should compare the value of `$book['author_id']` with the `$author['id']` inside the loop. Look Kuba's answer

Comment: my code is here, I'm using Web expression 4. http://www.mediafire.com/view/zcy913qg8fft7nf/form.php

Answer (score 1):

try it :

```
<div>
    <label>Select author here:</label>
    <select name="author">
        <option value="">Select an author</option>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
          <option value="<?php htmlout($author['id']);?>"
            <?php echo $Your_Select_value == $author['id'] ? "selected" : '';?> >    
            <?php htmlout($author['name']);?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't work, error: "In HTML 5 the  attribute <?php echo $Your_Select_value == $author['id'] ? "selected" : '';?> is not permitted for the <option> tag. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Proper value of `selected` attribute is `selected`. Thus if you wish to apply this attribute to the option that you consider currently selected, try this (I assume that PHP variable that stores selected author's id is `$authorid`):

```
<div>
    <label>Select author here:</label>
    <select name="author">
        <option value="">Select an author</option>
        <?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?>
          <option value="<?php htmlout($author['id']);?>" 
            <?php if ($author['id'] == $authorid) echo ('selected="selected"'); ?>
          >    
            <?php htmlout($author['name']);?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you prefer the ternary way : `($author['id'] == $authorid) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't put that PHP script into the place you show me, error: In HTML 5 the attribute <?php ... ?> is not permitted for the <option> tag.